# How to captureVisibleTab and save it to png file on server side?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In a Google Chrome extension, how can I captureVisibleTab and save it to png file on server side?

Comment: Just use chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab and XMLHttpRequest. What's your issue?

Comment: My issue is that I am beginner in google chrome extension so can someone write the code how it should be? Even can Pay for it:)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a simple example showing how you can do it:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "TabCapture",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Capture a tab",
  "background_page" : "background.html",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Capture tab"      
  },
  "permissions" : ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

background.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
</html>
```

background.js:

```
 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
   chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, function(img) {
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(), formData = new FormData();  
     formData.append("img", img);
     xhr.open("POST", "http://myserver.com/submitImage", true);
     xhr.send(formData);
   });
 });
```

This extension adds a browser action button in Chrome. When the user clicks on the button, a POST request containing the base64 encoded image (into a [FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Using_FormData_objects)) is sent to http://myserver.com/submitImage.

This code does not show how to manage errors and server response.

Comment: Thanks for advice I will try with this example